# I have two preg_matchs one is function and the other is not

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

This code is working

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.professor-oak.com/cardorders/ItemDetails.asp?IID=' . $row['POID']);
preg_match('#<span itemprop="price">(.*)</span>#', $content, $match);
$price = $match[1];
```

but this is not

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.trollandtoad.com/p1062197.html');
preg_match('#</div><div class="priceSection">$(.*)</div></div>#', $content, $match);
$price2 = $match[0];
echo $price;
```

and for the life of me i cannot figure out why.

I have tested the link and tested that information is being retrieved; both are working.

but i cannot get it to preg_match.
I am not running them on the same page.

Comment: `$` is a regex metacharacter that matches the end of line. Backslash it if you want to match a literal dollar sign.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)